# same code but print different results (recursive problem)

Tags: c, recursion, logic

this is simple recursive c code

`prt` function is print before call `prt`

```
#include<stdio.h>
int prt(int mul, int n){
    printf("%d %d\n", mul, n);
    if(n==0) {
        return mul;
    }
    mul = mul * n;
    prt(mul, n-1);
}

int prt2(int mul, int n){
    if(n==0) {
        return mul;
    }
    mul = mul * n;
    prt2(mul, n-1);
    printf("%d %d\n", mul, n);
}

int main()
{
   int n = 0;
   scanf("%d", &n);
   printf("test1: %d\n\n", prt(1, n));
   printf("test2: %d\n", prt2(1, n));
   return 0;
}
```

`prt2` function is print after call `prt`

why `test2` print 4..? i think print 120 like `test1` what's diff?

Comment: Suppose `prt()` is called with arguments (120, 0).  What happens?  Now suppose that `prt2()` is called with the same arguments.  What happens?

Comment: How do these different functions qualify as "same code"? They are obviously not same code. Also please enable your compiler warnings and fix them before you try to run your program.

Answer (score 1):

When the parameter n is not 0, neither `prt` nor `prt2` function returns a value, so if you input n is not 0, the return value should be undefined.

Comment: This is true but does not answer the question.